# Project Server 2013 : cannot create view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, project-server, pwa

I installed Project server 2013 on a SharePoint 2013 farm, everything goes well until I try to create a new view from "Project Web App Settings" page ==> the view doesn't get created (from the browser console I got

> internal server error 500).

And from the windows events viewer I got the exception below :

> Event code: 3003  Event message: A validation error has occurred.  Event time: 24/11/2016 11:49:00  Event time (UTC): 24/11/2016 10:49:00
>   Event ID: f1579d278df048f480b1deee3faa1c49  Event sequence: 245  Event
>   occurrence: 15  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1513911398/ROOT-2-131244510754673622 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: / 
>       Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\443\ 
>       Machine name: VMXXXXSPO    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 5128 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: Domain\XXXX   Exception information: 
>       Exception type: HttpRequestValidationException 
>       Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
>   (ctl00$ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$PWA_PlaceHolderMain$idGroupingSortingParams="0
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> ```
> Request information: 
> Request URL: https://XXXX.XXXX.com:443/_layouts/15/pwa/Admin/ViewsAddMod.aspx?idTableUID=&idViewType=
>
> Request path: /_layouts/15/pwa/Admin/ViewsAddMod.aspx 
> User host address: 66.160.201.34 
> User: 0#.w|XXX\sp_sql 
> Is authenticated: True 
> Authentication Type: Federation 
> Thread account name: XXXX\sp_sql    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 715 
> Thread account name: XXXX\sp_sql 
> Is impersonating: True 
> Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource
> ```
>
> requestCollection)    at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection
>   collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)    at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.GetParametersFromHttpRequest(SPSite
>   site, Boolean bAuthenticated)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
>   site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean
>   bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken
>   appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout,
>   Boolean bAsAnonymous)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb
>   web)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext
>   context)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_Current()    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.PJBasePage..ctor(String pwaUrl)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Project.PWA.PJWebPage..ctor(String url)    at
>   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_viewsaddmod_aspx_ad835a1b_jhjrehvf.Create_ASP__layouts_15_pwa_admin_viewsaddmod_aspx()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp)    at
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

What could be the problem?

PS :  I got the same error when trying to create calendar and when trying to add a user to a project server group.

**[update]**

This is what the PWA status looks like

[image: This is what the PWA status looks like]

I tried to restart the the timer Service without no result, the status is stuck on "Waiting for Resources"

**[update]**

Below the steps i do to reproduce the error :

[image]

[image]

Its like the save buton doesn't work and the view creation stack on the formulaire page.

PS : I have a frensh installation of project server

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the status of PWA instance ? is it provisioned ?

Comment: After verification i found that the status of PWA is " Provisioning Failed - see the Application event Log. " !! which is weird because the status was "provisioned" after the installation and i didn't do any actions!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that The `PWA instance` has been provisioned properly at

> Central administration > Application management > manage Service application > click on project server application server > check the status of your PWA Instance

[image]

- If it's not provisioned   try to provision it ,
- If PWA stuck on Waiting for Resources , just start SharePoint timer service as mentioned at [PWA stuck on Waiting for Resources during provisioning a new PWA Instance in Project Server](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/02/08/pwa-stuck-on-waiting-for-resources-during-provisioning/) ,

Comment: @soukaouta , you said you tried to restart SharePoint timer service, but still, you got waiting for resources ? are you applied this for all app servers within your farm ? are you tried to provision pwa again after restart timer service ?

Comment: The status is now Provisionned, i should have provisioned the pwa after restarting the timer sevice ==> Thanks for the information.
However, the error when creating a new view still exist with the same log trace.

Comment: go to iis > check application pool of PWA service check if it stopped , try to restart it by providing the service account credential again

Comment: Still not working :(
ps: the pwa portal is working fine and i can add projects and tasks ... normally, but the problem is when i try to create a new view from the "Project Web App Settings" page and also if i try to add a user to Project server administrators group ==> See picture below